# Barchart labels shouldn't go into the bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

`xAxis` Labels should not:

1. overlap with each other
2. go into the bars after rotation
3. overlaps with xAxis Title.

---

- After using:

  - `.call(xAxis).selectAll("text").attr("dx","-8em").attr("dy",".35em").attr("font-size","10").attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");` labels are overlapping with the title.
  - `padding= {bottom:50}` xAxis titles hides and goes into the margin.

[image]

Comment: Updated the format of the question and made the image inline

Comment: Thanks, @Trenton_M. Please tell me, "how have you done this?" I am new to stack overflow so that I can learn it.

Comment: There's an `edited x hours ago` link above my name.  Click it, then select the option `side-by-side markdown`.  That should allow you to see what I've done.  stack overflow answer and questions can use standard markdown, so you can also google search `markdown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `.attr('text-anchor', 'end')` in order to move the alignment point at the end of the text

Comment: I have tried that but didn't work out. Also, the Label size is not fixed because it's coming dynamically from the database so some times it didn't go into the bars but some times it does.

Comment: try to set `dx` and `dy` to `0` to see where the anchor point is